# I keep running into the same error when trying to run "npm start" in my terminal in VS code : npm not being able to find a file. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1G0J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwXdh.png)
I have tried to run "npm start" within my terminal on VS code on a mac. I keep running into the same issue.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/ericwehder/Desktop/Web Dev/Typescript/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ericwehder/Desktop/Web Dev/Typescript/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: can you post a picture of your folder and package.json file in which you r running this statement "npm start"

Comment: `no such file or directory, open '/Users/ericwehder/Desktop/Web Dev/Typescript/package.json'`. Make sure that there is a package.json file where you run the command `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

Inside `package.json` add this script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
```

Then run the following command in your terminal to start:

```
npm run dev
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#readme)